# Jqgrid breaks properties of other jqgrid

Tags: grails, jqgrid

As titled,

In my webpage, i have a jqgrid, and a button that will pop up a modal dialog that contains another jqgrid (displaying different data) on it. The problem is, the jqgrid on the modal dialog breaks the jqgrid on the page, like for example, if i set my jqgrid on the dialog to have no filter function, then it will cause the jqgrid's filter on the webpage to suddenly disappear.

Just want to know if anyone encounter such issues before?

By the way the webpage was created using Grails, so i'm not sure if this is related to Grails's resource issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to help you because you don't posted your code. I can only to suppose that you could have id conflicts between the grid in modal dialog and the grids on the main page. I would suggest you to add `idPrefix` option with some non-empty unique value in the modal dialog. For example you can add `idPrefix: "g1_"` in the first grid and `idPrefix: "g2_"` in the second grid. Then the rows with ids "1", "2", "3" will be `"g1_1"`, `"g1_2"`, `"g1_3"` in the first grid and there will be `"g2_1"`, `"g2_2"`, `"g2_3"` in the second grid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I didn't post my code because i don't know what should be posted. I skimmed through the code and was sure the ids and columns name were different, but just for testing i made changes according to your advice but nothing helps. I suppose its because of code conflict between the modal and webpage that causes this?

Comment: @Oleg Please, when you have a chance, can you look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141013/deleting-jqgrid-rows-with-local-data-results-in-unclickable-cells)