# Deleting jqGrid rows with local data results in unclickable cells

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with my jqGrid.

- It is using local data
- It is setup to allow inline (cell editing)

When I delete a row (locally only) using the `delRowData` method, the row is deleted as expected. However when I delete a couple of rows, the inline cell editing seems to stop working.

When this happens I don't see any errors in the chrome debug window. I've setup a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdwdxLuk/1/)**

Here is the grid definition

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int",
        editable : false
    }, {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date",
        editable : true,
        edittype : 'text'
    }, {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30,
        editable : true,
        edittype : 'text'
    }, {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float",
        editable : true,
        edittype : 'text'
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float",
        editable : true,
        edittype : 'text'
    }],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
    cellEdit    : true,
    cellsubmit  : 'clientArray'
});
```

Here is my delete method. I've made it as simple as I can. It just always deletes the first row.

```
function deleteRow() {
    var ids = $("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    $("#grid").jqGrid('delRowData', ids[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following: cell editing of jqGrid are written so that it works mostly with row indexes (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp)) instead of rowids. Some internal structures of jqGrid (`savedRows` and `iRow` options) and the id of editable cell will be assigned with the value which constructed based on the index of editable row. So after deleting of a row in the grid the information need be updated.

I modified your jsfiddle demo to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/wdwdxLuk/14/. It uses the following code of `deleteRow` called if one clicks on the button "Delete the first Row of the grid":

```
function deleteRow() {
    var $grid = $("#grid"), editingTr, rows, iRow, editingColumnName,
        p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), // get reference to object with jqGrid options
        savedRows = p.savedRow, //{id:iRow, ic:iCol, name:nm, v:cellData};
        colModel = p.colModel;

    if ($grid.length > 0 && $grid[0].rows.length > 1) {
        rows = $grid[0].rows;
        editingTr = savedRows.length > 0 ? rows[savedRows[0].id] : undefined;
        // delete the row
        $("#grid").jqGrid('delRowData', rows[1].id); // delete the first row (rows[0] don't contains any data)
        if (editingTr !== undefined) {
            // update the index of the editing row
            iRow = editingTr.rowIndex;
            if (iRow < 0) {
                // editing row way deleted from the grid
                p.savedRow = [];
                delete p.iRow;
                delete p.iCol;
            } else {
                // update the row index in savedRows
                editingColumnName = colModel[savedRows[0].ic].name;
                $(editingTr).find("#" + savedRows[0].id + "_" + $.jgrid.jqID(editingColumnName))
                    .attr("id", iRow + "_" + editingColumnName);
                savedRows[0].id = iRow;
                // update row index of selected row
                p.iRow = iRow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer Oleg. Let me parse through all this code and make sure it fits my more complicated grid. This delete operation is a lot more complex!

Comment: @jasonscript: You are welcome! Cell editing in the oldest editing mode of jqGrid. As I wrote cell editing saves the row index in internal structure. So I see no other way to fix the problem as writing relatively long code like above. I inserted comments to make understanding of the required changes in `savedRows`, `iRow` and `id` of editing cell more easy.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, thanks for your help so far. I've found a small bug in your **jsFiddle**: (1) Edit 'Thingy' for row 48803
(2) Delete row 48803
(3) Edit any cell
(4) The 'Thingy' value for rowIndex 1 gets cleared

Comment: @jasonscript: I'm a little busy now. I will reproduce the problem and fix the code later.

Comment: @jasonscript: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/wdwdxLuk/14/ . One needs just change `savedRows = [];` to `p.savedRow = [];`